# Snake Draft - Overall Order Position (Math Related)

Tags: javascript, math

So I'm creating a Fantasy Football draft helper, and it's a 12-team snake draft format, which proceeds 1 through 12 LTR, then 13 through 24 RTL, then 25 through 36 LTR

----->

<-----

------>

So, the person with the `#1` overall position (Team A) also finds themselves in the `#24` and `#25` position.

The `#12` position also has the `#13` position, as the order "wraps around" a grid.

[Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nrpN.png)

Here is what I have come up with to flag any team's overall orders dynamically, based on draft position, but I'm no math whiz, and it seems wonky to have a special case for position=1 that doesn't apply to any of the other cases.  This works, but I want to know what the *real* math is for this, if anyone knows.

Here is a fiddle I created with some sample code, based on my current solution.

```
var TEAMS = 12;
var ROUNDS = 4; 
var POS = 1;
var $overallOrder = $('#overallOrder');
var total = TEAMS * ROUNDS;
if (POS > TEAMS) { alert("only " + TEAMS + " teams"); return false; }
for (var i=1; i<=total; i++) {
    var isMyTurn = false;
    if ((i % (2*TEAMS)) == ((2*TEAMS) - (POS-1))) {
        isMyTurn = true;
    }
    if ((i % (2*TEAMS)) == POS) {
        isMyTurn = true;
    }
    //special case for first position ?
    if (POS==1 && (i % (2*TEAMS)) == 0) {
        isMyTurn = true;
    }
    var turnText = (isMyTurn) ? i + " My Turn!" : i ;
    $overallOrder.append('<li>'+turnText+'</li>');    
}
```

Try changing the POS var from 1-12 and you can see the results.  Again, I'm looking for the mathematical function that would encapsulate the above logic, if anyone knows.  Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/3oy1w71c/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in your code would be nice.

The fundamental problem is that `%` runs from `0` to `2*TEAMS-1`, but you’re thinking from `1` to `2*TEAMS`: you end up needing a special case for `POS==1` is because `(2*TEAMS)-(POS-1)` turns out to be `2*TEAMS`, but `i%(2*TEAMS)` is never `2*TEAMS`.  The easy fix is to change it to `((2*TEAMS)-(POS-1))%(2*TEAMS)`.  This allows you to get things down to

```
var turnText = i;

if ((i % (2*TEAMS)) == ((2*TEAMS)-(POS-1))%(2*TEAMS) 
    || (i % (2*TEAMS)) == POS) {
    turnText += " My Turn!";
}
```

Another approach is to use `(i-1)%(2*TEAMS)+1` to get the modulus into `1` to `2*TEAMS`.

If you want to get it down to one conditional not using `||`, you can exploit the symmetry of the snake around `TEAMS+.5`.

```
if ( Math.abs(TEAMS+.5-((i-1)%(2*TEAMS)+1))==TEAMS+.5-POS )
```

But I find this harder to read than the previous version.

Comment: Thanks, this will take me a while to fully get my head around, but it does seem to work!  http://jsfiddle.net/3oy1w71c/2/